# When I run the code only one worksheet is updated eg Apple. The other 3 worksheets are not updated. How can I solve this?

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the code only one worksheet is updated eg Apple. The other 3 worksheets are not updated. The code is trying to change zero values to blanks in the worksheets. The code is running through the whole macro but worksheets Orange, Grape, and Pear not updating. How can I solve this?

```
Sub ReturnZerosAsBlanks()

    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'Declare variables and objects'
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
       
   'Objects'
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsApple As Worksheet
    Dim wsOrange As Worksheet
    Dim wsGrape As Worksheet
    Dim wsPear As Worksheet

       
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'Define variables and objects'
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'set workbooks and worksheets'
    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsApple = wbk.Sheets("Apple")
    Set wsOrange = wbk.Sheets("Orange")
    Set wsGrape = wbk.Sheets("Grape")
    Set wsPear = wbk.Sheets("Pear")

    
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'Application settings'
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'Remove zeros from blank linked cells

    'Column AA:AB in tab Apple
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim WorkRng1 As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng1 = wsApple(Range("AA2"), Range("AB2").End(xlDown))
    For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
        If Rng1.Value = 0 Then
        Rng1.Value = ""
    End If
    Next Rng1


    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'Remove zeros from blank linked cells

    'Column A:D in tab Orange
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim WorkRng2 As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng2 = wsOrange.Range(Range("A2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If Rng2.Value = 0 Then
        Rng2.Value = ""
    End If
    Next Rng2

    
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'Remove zeros from blank linked cells

    'Column AD in tab Grape
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    
    Dim Rng3 As Range
    Dim WorkRng3 As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng3 = wsGrape(Range("AD2"), Range("AD2").End(xlDown))
    For Each Rng3 In WorkRng3
        If Rng3.Value = 0 Then
        Rng3.Value = ""
    End If
    Next Rng3
    


    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'Remove zeros from blank linked cells

    'Column G in tab Pear
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    
    Dim Rng4 As Range
    Dim WorkRng4 As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng4 = wsPear.Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
    For Each Rng4 In WorkRng
        If Rng4.Value = 0 Then
        Rng4.Value = ""
    End If
    Next Rng4



    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    'Application settings'
    '*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'*'
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `On Error Resume Next` and you'll get an error message on the problematic lines.

Comment: This line needs a 4: `For Each Rng4 In WorkRng`

Comment: Are you aware there is a setting in Excel for whether to display a zero or a blank cell? It operates per worksheet. On my install: File -> Options -> Advanced -> Display options for this worksheet -> Show a zero in cells that have a zero value

Comment: Looks like to do it from code you actually have to select the sheet then call `ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Replace in Multiple Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReturnZerosAsBlanks()

    ' Constants
    Dim SheetNames As Variant
    SheetNames = VBA.Array("Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Pear")
    Dim Cols As Variant
    Cols = VBA.Array("AA:AB", "A:D", "AD", "G")
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Toggle application settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Remove zeros from blank linked cells.
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range, LastRow As Long, j As Long
    
    ' Loop through worksheets with names supplied in Sheet Names Array.
    For j = 0 To UBound(SheetNames)
        
        ' Define Current Worksheet.
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SheetNames(j))
        ' Using always the first column, calculate Last Row.
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Columns(Cols(j)).Column) _
                    .End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow < 2 Then GoTo NextSheet
        ' Define Criteria Range.
        Set rng = ws.Columns(Cols(j)).Rows(2).Resize(LastRow - 1) ' 1 = 2 - 1
        
        ' This is faster, but doesn't work for formulas, although you should
        ' not do this when there are formulas in cells.
        rng.Replace What:=0, _
                    Replacement:=Empty, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole

        ' This will work for formulas, too.
'        For Each cel In rng.Cells
'            If cel.Value = 0 Then
'                cel.Value = Empty
'            End If
'        Next cel
NextSheet:
    Next j
    
    ' Toggle application settings.
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008 , this has solved the question at hand!